# Discord.py sending multiple files at once with a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a discord bot that when I write `$doit` it sends all the files in the image folder but I would like it to do it one by one

So basically make a for loop and send the images

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Logged in as')
  print(client.user.name)
  print(client.user.id)
  print('------')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$doit'):
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File("./images/*"))

client.run("OT*****************************************")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code that works fine:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Logged in as')
  print(bot.user.name)
  print(bot.user.id)
  print('------')

@bot.command()
async def doit(ctx):
    dir_path = r"your directory path here"
    res = []  # empty list to be filled up with your files names

    for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
            res.append(path)

    for r in res:
        with open(dir_path + "\\" + r, 'rb') as f:
            picture = discord.File(f)
            await ctx.channel.send(file=picture)


bot.run("your token here")
```

What I've done:

1. I've made `$doit` a command, since it's rather a command, not an event. I've defined your prefix as `$` and `doit` as the command/function.
2. I've used `os` library to list all the files in the directory you can define as `dir_path` variable and add the files names to the `res` list.
3. I've made a `for` loop just as you said to send every file from `res` list as a separate message.

It worked fine for me.

If you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask. :)

P.S. Now it sends every file in a directory, no matter if it is an image or not. You can limit it to just images using a simple `if` condition and specify the extensions of the files (`.jpg`, `.png`, etc.).